# how to import the another tkinter python class code to open the new tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two *tkinter* **class1.py** and **class2.py**. I face the problem that when i import the **class2.py** in **class1.py** it executes the **class2.py** first then only execute **class1.py**.

**###class 1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk 
import class2
from class2 import root2
class MyApp1(object): 

    def __init__(self, parent): 

        self.root1 = parent 

        self.root1.title("Main frame") 
 
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent) 

        self.frame.pack() 

        btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Open Frame", command=) 

        btn.pack()

    def call(self):
        self.root1.withdraw()
        x = class2.MyApp2(root2)                                                              

root1 = tk.Tk()

root1.geometry("800x600")
                                                  
app = MyApp1(root1)
                                             
root1.mainloop()
```

**###class2.py**

```
import tkinter as tk 

class MyApp2(object): 

    def __init__(self, parent): 

        self.root2 = parent 

        self.root2.title("Main frame") 
 
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent) 

        self.frame.pack() 

        btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Open Frame", command=self.openFrame) 

        btn.pack()  
                                                         
    def openFrame(self):
        pass

root2 = tk.Tk()

root2.geometry("800x600")
                                                  
#app = MyApp2(root2)
                                             
root2.mainloop()
```

Now How can I import the **class2.py** from the **class1.py** and outcome becomes **class1 tkinter** window then only **class2 tkinter** window?

Comment: You can simply put the lines from `root2 = tk.Tk()` to the end into a function, for example `show()`, then you can call `class2.show()` inside `MyApp1.call()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be importing code like this. The proper way to make your code importable is to make sure it only has functions and class definitions. Then, the code that does the importing is responsible for calling the functions and instantiating the classes.

class2.py should look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class MyApp2(object): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        self.root2 = parent 
        self.root2.title("Main frame") 
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent) 
        self.frame.pack() 
        btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Open Frame", command=self.openFrame) 
        btn.pack()  
                                                         
    def openFrame(self):
        pass
```

class1.py can now safely import this file. It can then create the instance of `MyApp2` like this:

```
def call(self):
    self.root1.withdraw()
    new_window = tk.Toplevel()
    class2.MyApp2(new_window)
```

Or, if you no longer need the main window, you can destroy everything inside the main window and then reuse it for the new class:

```
def call(self):
    for child in self.root1.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    class2.MyApp2(self.root1)
```

Comment: it also be possible to write tk.Toplevel()  instead of tk. Tk() in  which we want to import the tkinter window.i solve using this technique.